# Duplicates in Pandas Dataframe after Self Merge

Tags: python, pandas, merge, duplicates, self-join

```
import pandas as pd
```

I have a Dataframe Table

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID_A':[1, 2, 3], 'name':['Micha', 'Micha', 'Lea']})

-----------------
- ID_A   - name  
-----------------
- 1      - Micha 
- 2      - Micha 
- 3      - Lea   
-----------------
```

I wanna do a self join to get the following

```
---------------------------
- ID_A_x - name  - ID_A_y -
---------------------------
- 1      - Micha - 1      -
- 1      - Micha - 2      -
- 3      - Lea   - 3      -
---------------------------
```

But with

```
pd.merge(d1, d1, left_on='name', right_on='name', how='left')
```

i get duplicate pairs that are the same for me, how to avoid them?
This result is not what i want:

```
---------------------------
- ID_A_x - name  - ID_A_y -
---------------------------
- 1      - Micha - 1      -
- 1      - Micha - 2      -
- 2      - Micha - 2      -
- 2      - Micha - 1      -
- 3      - Lea   - 3      -
---------------------------
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Imgur]

```
pd.DataFrame({'ID_A_x':[1,1,2,2,3],
             'name':['Mi','Mi','Mi','Mi','Lea'],
             'ID_A_y':[1,2,2,1,3]}).drop_duplicates(['ID_A_y','name'])
```

Comment: This is perfect for cleaning it up afterwards. Thank you.

Comment: hi @loegare, may i have lib name for showing "executed in ..ms, finished...."

Comment: @rean its a jupyter notebook extension, dont remember the exact name

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that I understood you correctly. But one possible solution (which I think is what you want) could be:

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID_A':[1, 2, 3], 'name':['Micha', 'Micha', 'Lea']})
pd.merge(d1.drop_duplicates(subset='name'), d1, on='name', how='left')
```

Output:

```
   ID_A_x   name  ID_A_y
0       1  Micha       1
1       1  Micha       2
2       3    Lea       3
```

Comment: Works, Thank you.

Comment: I seem to be having this same issue.  Dropping duplicates might work, but it concerns me that it produces them in the first place.  Is there a better solution?

Comment: @ColoradoGranite The reason for the duplicates is that we have non-unique keys. We merge on 'name' and Micha is two times in that column. The only way to avoid duplicates would be to have unique keys, I think. So to answer your question, I can't find anything better with the above data.